# How do I maintain unique items in a list thereby solving this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, azure-notebooks

I require to create a program that provides the solution:

> 1
>  3 2
>  6 5 4
>  10 9 8 7

using python.

I've been trying out different ideas for over three weeks, and I can't find a solution. 
All of the code functions/commands that I am permitted to use have been used in the following attempts.

Various attempts include:

The first piece of code shows some promise, but it keeps getting duplicate items in the x list.

```py
    #Attempt 1
    n=4
    l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    x = [0]
    for i in range (0, n+1):
        k = 0
        j = i
        while k <= i and j != x[j-1]:
            j += l[k]
            print (j, end = " ")
            x.append(j)
            while j != i and j != x[j-1]:
                j -= 1
                if j > i:
                    print (j, end = " ")
                    x.append(j)
            print (x)
            k+=1

    #Attempt 2
    n = 4 
    print (1)
    for a in range (2, n):
        for i in range (2, n*2, a):
            j = i 
            j+=i-1
            print (j, end =" ")
            while j>i:
                j-=1
                print (j, end= " ")
            print ()

    #Attempt 3
    n = 4
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    for i in range (0, n):
        for j in range (0, n*3, l[i]):
            while j >= i:
                print (j, end = " ")
                j-=1
            print ()
```

The output ought to be

> 1
>  3 2
>  6 5 4
>  10 9 8 7

in some form or the other, but I never get it.

Comment: Some ideas you can consider: the nth line contains n values, and the last of these values is 1+2+...n, which is equal to n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by cdlane is more pythonic. This is simplified (school project) version.

```
n = 4

for i in range(1, n+1):
  max_num_in_line = i * (i+1)// 2  # this gives max number to be printed in line i
  for j in range(i): # here i is the total numbers to be printed in a line.
    print(max_num_in_line, end=' ')
    max_num_in_line -= 1
  print()
```

Comment: Helped IMMENSELY.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to get that particular output, knowing only the value of `n`, then you can do:

```
n = 8

numbers = range(1, n * (n + 1) // 2 + 1)

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    head, numbers = numbers[:i], numbers[i:]
    print(*reversed(head))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1
3 2
6 5 4
10 9 8 7
15 14 13 12 11
21 20 19 18 17 16
28 27 26 25 24 23 22
36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
>
```

Or is there more to this problem that I'm not getting?

Comment: That seems to solve it, BUT I haven't learned that yet, so I can't use that code. Thanks though!

Comment: @ScalyV: 1) I simplifed the answer a bit; 2) how are we supposed to know what you have or have not learned yet?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have included that. I'll make the edit, but just for you to know, I've used all the commands that I've been taught. But thanks for your code as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicated values you should use `set()` instead of `list()` on the `x` variable.

Comment: Hey Mahund! I've considered using sets in the past, but since they haven't been covered by our course, I can't use them.